# NSLayout Constraint to hide UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, storyboard

I'm trying to recreate this but I can't figure out how to hook this constraint up:

There is a constraint to the `RootViewController` in the storyboard where the "Installed" checkbox is not checked:

[image]

But it looks like its relationship is to the `RootViewController` even though it hides the second Container View:

[image]

I've tried creating the `IBOutlet` in code with `@IBOutlet weak var hideCameraConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!` and then dragging a connection to the `RootViewController` in the Storyboard but that didn't work.

But I need to use the constraint because in code the camera visibility is set with it:

```
fileprivate func setCameraVisibility(_ visible: Bool) {
    hideCameraConstraint.isActive = !visible
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of setting isActive, can you try modifying the constant attribute?

Comment: are you want to hide and unhide view on some action?

Comment: @carlos21 I'm really just trying to figure out how to add that constraint on the storyboard mainly.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Nazir yeah I want to hide and unhide the camera view.  Basically be able to show or hide the ability to take a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for hiding and unhiding the view with constraints use such method:

1. set Constraint with `height == 0` add Identifier `hideViewIdentifier`
2. set height Constraint Priority to `250`
3. set Priority to conflicting Constraint to `900` (in your case this will be the bottom layout or actual height)

and then update Priority to hide Constraint between `250` to show view and `990` to hide the view

```
//@update
- (void)upadteView:(UIView *)view hide:(BOOL)hide {
    [view.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof NSLayoutConstraint * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if ([obj.identifier isEqual:@"hideViewIdentifier"]) {
            obj.priority = (hide) ? 990 : 250;
            *stop = YES;
            return;
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I think I'm looking for, let me try it out though today!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to manually drag over a constraint still

Comment: what do you mean with drag over?

Comment: that "Hide Camera Constraint" on the Storyboard

Comment: I think better will be to start chat as this is the topic and is not good to make long conversation

Answer (score 2):

You have to use like this

```
    hideCameraConstraint.constant += anyValue
```

In constraint you have to set integer values not a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How would I hook up the constraint in Storyboard though?

Comment: @SRMR i am giving you example suppose you use UIView in storyboard and setting its leading constraint to 50, then you have to attach these constraint to your created constraint i.e hideCameraConstraint. Now in program you can change leading constraint of your UIView. example - hideCameraConstraint.constant = 20 , it means now your UIView leading from 20 not 50, in this way you can change constraint programatically.  If you like my answer please upvote my answer.

Comment: Right, what I'm looking for is how to hook up the constraint I was looking for in storyboard